# Canvas loop class elements TypeError: $this.getContext is not a function

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

I don't know why have error i making code same like this:
http://jsfiddle.net/kMN3s/2/.
This is sorter in my web. I want make canvas buttons looks like arrows.

HTML:

```
<div id="sortbtn">
      <a href="#" class="top" date-color-arrow="#FF0000"><canvas class="arrowup"></canvas></a>
      <a href="#" date-color-arrow="#000000"><canvas class="arrowdown"></canvas></a>
      <a href="#" class="top" date-color-arrow="#000000"><canvas class="arrowup"></canvas></a>
      <a href="#" date-color-arrow="#000000"><canvas class="arrowdown"></canvas></a>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
        $('#sortMm a').each(function () {
            $this = $(this).find('canvas');
            var colorArrow = $(this).attr('date-color-arrow');
            var stanceArrow = this.getElementsByClassName('top');
            if (stanceArrow == true) {
                var arrowtop = $this.getContext("2d");
                arrowtop.fillStyle = colorArrow;
                arrowtop.beginPath();
                arrowtop.moveTo(5, 0);
                arrowtop.lineTo(9, 5);
                arrowtop.lineTo(0, 5);
                arrowtop.lineTo(5, 0);
                arrowtop.closePath();
                arrowtop.fill();
            } else {
                var arrowbottom = $this.getContext("2d");
                arrowbottom.fillStyle = colorArrow;
                arrowbottom.beginPath();
                arrowbottom.moveTo(5, 5);
                arrowbottom.lineTo(0, 0);
                arrowbottom.lineTo(9, 0);
                arrowbottom.lineTo(5, 5);
                arrowtop.closePath();
                arrowbottom.fill();
            }
        });
```

Comment: You cannot use `.getContext()` on a jQuery object. You rather need the "underlying" DOM object: `canvas = $this[0]; var arrowbottom = canvas.getContext("2d");`

Comment: @devnull69: I'd suggest you post that as the answer, because it is.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$(this).find("canvas").get(0).getContext("2d");
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `.getContext()` on a jQuery object. You rather need the "underlying" DOM object. This can be achieved by using the `[0]` array index on the jQuery object.

```
$('#sortMm a').each(function () {
        var canvas = $(this).find('canvas')[0];
        var colorArrow = $(this).attr('date-color-arrow');
        var stanceArrow = this.getElementsByClassName('top');
        if (stanceArrow == true) {
            var arrowtop = canvas.getContext("2d");
            arrowtop.fillStyle = colorArrow;
            arrowtop.beginPath();
            arrowtop.moveTo(5, 0);
            arrowtop.lineTo(9, 5);
            arrowtop.lineTo(0, 5);
            arrowtop.lineTo(5, 0);
            arrowtop.closePath();
            arrowtop.fill();
        } else {
            var arrowbottom = canvas.getContext("2d");
            arrowbottom.fillStyle = colorArrow;
            arrowbottom.beginPath();
            arrowbottom.moveTo(5, 5);
            arrowbottom.lineTo(0, 0);
            arrowbottom.lineTo(9, 0);
            arrowbottom.lineTo(5, 5);
            arrowtop.closePath();
            arrowbottom.fill();
        }
});
```